# When can the app model change?

Tags: elm

I'm wondering when the app model might change.

Specifically, is code like this guaranteed to be correct, or not?

`onClick <| UpdateModelVersionMessage (model.version + 1)`

That is, between rendering the UI component, and registering and dispatching the event, could something else update the model such that the `UpdateModelVersionMessage` value is out of date? Javascript's concurrency model makes me believe I'm safe. But is Elm doing or could Elm possibly do something like batching/reordering messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been informed that, as of 0.18:

> The view is rendered asynchronously through requestanimationframe so, **no, it's not safe**.

But also:

> in 0.19, html events will trigger synchronous rerenders, so that will not be a problem

And finally:

> Requestanimationframe runs at 60fps, tho, so the window for events to be sent with an outdated model is really small
>   i.e. 16ms at most, assuming your view can render within a single frame (if it can't, that's a different issue)
>   So in this case, **I'd recommend doing the simplest thing that could possibly work, knowing the odds of it going wrong are *very very* slim, and knowing that in 0.19, the view can re-render synchronously, preventing this from being an possible issue altogether**

Thanks to Ilias (https://github.com/zwilias) for the answers.